# Portlets are removed/undeployed from Liferay on shutdown or restart of portal

Tags: deployment, liferay, portlet

I have an astonishing problem: On restart of Liferay portal some portlets are undeployed, but not always and I cannot reproduce when and why this is happening.

The problem is that after restart the portlets are undeployed and must be redeployed again.

Comment: Liferay version? On which server (tomcat or jboss)? Are you sharing the portal server with other developers?

Comment: Liferay 6.0.x EE, Tomcat, no, other developer don't remove the portlets :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Do the following steps to get more details on the error.

In the portlet `WEB-INF/classes` folder add the file `logging.properties` and add the following lines of code:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

This will give more details on the issue. After you add this file, try to recreate the issue and check the logs.

This is for `Liferay`(any version) running on Tomcat.